# Magento 1.8.1.0 : No Subcategories on home screen

Tags: magento-1.8, category, menu, home

On our website **www.circuit-parts.ch** the subcategories will not be shown on the start screen when you roll over with the mouse.

But, if you click a category, on the second page it shows all subcategories by roll over with the mouse.

So the problem is only on the start screen.. on the first page..
why is that?

**Theme: Fortis 2.0.2-B**

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are using jquery in combination with prototype.
On your homepage the file `js/infortis/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js` is not loaded in the dom. On the other pages it is included.
Include that in your homepage and it will work.

**[Edit]**
There is also this line in your homepage

```
<script src="/layerslider/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This loads jquery again but it does not add `jQuery.noConflict()`. Edit that file also and add the noConflict statement.
But you should not load jquery twice on the page. You can remove that line completely. I have no idea where it comes from. It can be the homepage content from the CMS->Pages section or from a widget.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your first help.
Can you please explain to me a little more? What do you mean by not loaded in the "dom" ?
how can i include that in the page?
sorry for my newbie questions...

Comment: To make things easier. just edit the file `js/infortis/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and add this line at the end of the file `jQuery.noConflict()`.

Comment: seems it doesn't work... i added jQuery.noConflict() at the end like you said but no change.... is it possible to mail you the file to take a look?

Comment: @Stefan See my update

Comment: ok i removed the line you said. 
<script src="/layerslider/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
i found it in a static block like you said. but after deleting the line the whole layerslider did no work... after put back the deleted line the slider still not working.... 
now i deactivated the slider... the kategories are showing right now....